# Calculate word numbers from Tkinter's indices

Tags: python, tkinter, indices

I stumbled upon this problem a long time ago, but I still cannot find the answer. Say, I have Tkinter's indices in the Text widget such as '4.5', '2.3', etc. I need to calculate corresponding word numbers or char positions and vice versa.

I can do the integers to indices conversion as follows:

```
postk = '1.0+%dc' % (pos - sentence_no)
```

but I still need to know the number of the current sentence.
The indices to integers conversion is harder: I need to split the index ('4.5'), get the number of chars in the 3rd sentence and add up 5. This is not very difficult, but I see this as unnecessary calculations.

Maybe there is a more simple way to do this? Using tkinter's `.get()` to get the corresponding string and then doing `text.index(search)` is no-way, because there could be multiple matches through the text.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your question, but perhaps [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.dump-method) is what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I just don't want to mess around with tkinter's coordinates. I want to use integers (1st, 2nd, 3rd symbol - 0, 1, 2) instead of '1.0', '1.1', '1.2'.